# php, http_build_query, &amp;

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте. Работаю с VK Callback API, необходимо выполнить запрос к API (file_get_contents), но данная функция почему-то заменяет `&` на `&amp;`

```
$request_params = array( 
      'message' => "Hello, {$user_name}", 
      'user_id' => $user_id, 
      'access_token' => $token, 
      'v' => '5.0' 
); 

$get_params = http_build_query($request_params,'', '&');

file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'.$get_params);
```

Как можно этого избежать?

Comment: Не должно такого быть. Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b4f0799be630507c475a37ac4f680d88e6a03dd6

Comment: Зачем вы указываете 2 и 3 аргументы у функции `http_build_query()`? Функция прекрасно и без них построит вам нужную query-строку.